# Redirecting url with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect http://example.com/forum/index.php to http://example.com/forum/ and it will not work. Here's the code I'm using in my .htaccess. What am I doing wrong?

```
Redirect forum/index.php http://example.com/forum
```

I've also tried without the forum/ part too.

Comment: can you give the full contents of your .htaccess? Where in your path is this .htaccess file living?

Comment: I'm on my own Apache server and the only thing that's in my .htaccess is that. The .htaccess file is located in my htdocs file.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a / before forum:

```
Redirect /forum/index.php http://example.com/forum/
```

Comment: It didn't work.